# Can't get checkboxes to work google sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

I have little to no experience with google scripts, and I find myself in a pickle.
I want to execute a script when a checkbox is checked. I got this working.
The problem is i can't make the script take into account other checkboxes - say i have 3 options for the script -> log ALL, log only fruits and add the store. It runs when i click RUN, but it won't take into account my "log fruit" checkbox.
At the end it will set the checkbox that runs the script back to FALSE.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.columnEnd == 6 && e.range.rowStart == 7 && e.range.rowEnd == 7 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    if (e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.columnEnd == 6 && e.range.rowStart == 4 && e.range.rowEnd == 4 && e.value == "TRUE") {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 6).setValue(10);
    }
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 8).setValue(20);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 6).setValue("FALSE");
  }
}
```

Any ideas ?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BtDoO3QIGaiZxUYTld5Si8die1W-O_1FiqczqgN8diI/edit#gid=1776658601

Comment: Can you explain? Where do you want to put 10? If you test first the row at 7 and then at 4, nothing will happen! The row can't be at the same time 4 and 7.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Why the nested if?

Comment: Hey ! This is great, but not exactly what I am trying to get. The first 3 checkboxes are options for the calculate “”. So I have 10 columns, and I copy by default 5 columns. If I select add apples, and when I click calculate it copies the 5 columns plus the 6th - Apples. Same for the other 2 checkboxes. It adds the store. I managed to get it to work by creating a function name xxx. Apparently on edit does not count the other checkboxes before. I was thinking of calling this function in the onEdit one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Automating with onEdit

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const ops = ["","Add all","Add only Apple","Add store","Calculating"]
  if (sh.getName() == "Simplified_data" && e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart > 3 && e.range.rowStart < 9 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    let idx = ops.indexOf(e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue())
    if(idx > 0) {
      e.source.toast(ops[idx]);
      //complete your operations in here
    }
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Hey ! This is great, but not exactly what I am trying to get. The first 3 checkboxes are options for the calculate “”. 
So I have 10 columns, and I copy by default 5 columns. If I select add apples, and when I click calculate it copies the 5 columns plus the 6th - Apples. Same for the other 2 checkboxes. It adds the store. 

I managed to get it to work by creating a function name xxx. Apparently on edit does not count the other checkboxes before.

Comment: It was not very clear to me what you wanted so I simply provided you with the logic to get into the onEdit(e) function knowing which button was clicked.  From here you should be able to provide the additional logic to begin to complete it your self  If you wish a more complete example then please provide additional explanation with before and after examples.

Comment: Thanks once again. I love what you did, I will implement as much as possible, and will come back if I encounter any issues. I will chose this as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.columnEnd == 6 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 8).setValue(20);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 6).setValue("FALSE");
  }
}
```